# Why does the * print first in my output?

Tags: bash

In my script i have a variable that's supplied by a curl command where i'm grabbing the 'Location' value from the response. (it's a redirect).

I know i could use -L but i actually can't for some specific reasons. Anyway, here's part of my script.

```
# remove any spaces and remove any newlines
REDIR=$(echo $REDIR | sed "s/[[:blank:]]//g" | tr -d '\n')
echo "^$REDIR*"
# split on the : and save the variable 
NEWSID=$(echo $REDIR | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
echo "^$NEWSID*"
```

Interestingly, the output on my screen is

```
*Location:/frame/prompt/new?sid=MDc0M2YwMTc5ZDZjNDEwOGIyZTA4YWM5M2VjNjFjNTA%3D%7C50.165.98.133%7C1401427310%7C1f75fea94a7ecdb28833f22e51794cb1eb5726e1
*/frame/prompt/new?sid=MDc0M2YwMTc5ZDZjNDEwOGIyZTA4YWM5M2VjNjFjNTA%3D%7C50.165.98.133%7C1401427310%7C1f75fea94a7ecdb28833f22e51794cb1eb5726e1
```

Which is puzzling to me because i'd expect a ^ as the first character.

Am i doing something wrong? None of the other variables cause this.

Comment: You can use `echo "${REDIR}"` before `echo "^$REDIR*"` to see what's `REDIR` set to. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the second form using `echo`.

Comment: Your string contains carriage returns too.  Remove those as well: `REDIR=$(echo $REDIR | sed "s/[[:blank:]]//g" | tr -d '\r\n')`

Comment: @r-sahu I used the ^ and * to see where the darn problem was. i tried the {} but it prints properly obscuring the issue.